# Columnwise sum of a data frame with different data types in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with multiple columns and I want to add a top row with sum of all the columns.

```
mydf
id name val1 val2 val3 val4
1 abc 1 3 2.2 3.1
2 def 2 3 3.2 1.3
```

This is what I am trying

```
tot<-mydf %>%
    summarize_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But this would only show sum for val1 and val2.

```
Desired output

id name val1 val2 val3 val4
Total  3 6 5.4 4.4
1 abc 1 3 2.2 3.1
2 def 2 3 3.2 1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `adorn_totals`

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
   adorn_totals()
```

-output

```
   id name val1 val2 val3 val4
     1  abc    1    3  2.2  3.1
     2  def    2    3  3.2  1.3
 Total    -    3    6  5.4  4.4
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
   summarise(id = c('', id), name = c('Total', name), 
     across(starts_with('val'), ~c(sum(., na.rm = TRUE), .)))
  id  name val1 val2 val3 val4
1    Total    3    6  5.4  4.4
2  1   abc    1    3  2.2  3.1
3  2   def    2    3  3.2  1.3
```

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = 1:2, name = c("abc", "def"), val1 = 1:2, 
    val2 = c(3L, 3L), val3 = c(2.2, 3.2), val4 = c(3.1, 1.3)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tibble::add_row`:

```
library(tibble)

add_row(mydf, name  = "Total", 
        summarize(mydf, across(starts_with("val"), ~ sum(., na.rm = T))))
```

By default, it is appended to the bottom.

**Output**

```
  id  name val1 val2 val3 val4
1  1   abc    1    3  2.2  3.1
2  2   def    2    3  3.2  1.3
3 NA Total    3    6  5.4  4.4
```